# jQuery: How can I assign a variable back to a hidden element in the document?

Tags: jquery, html, hidden-field

How can I assign a variable (button id that was clicked), to the jQuery Diaglog, then back to the hidden element (myhiddenid) in the document for later use?

```
<table border="0" class="time_data">
    <td><button type="button" id='001' class="del-fruit" > Apple </td>
    <td><button type="button" id='002' class="del-fruit" > Banana </td>
    <td><button type="button" id='003' class="del-fruit" > Cantalope </td>
</table>

<div id='myhiddenid' style="display:none;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 150,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        'Yes': function() {
            var bValid = true;
            allFields.removeClass('ui-state-error');

            bValid = bValid 

            if (bValid) {
                //the assining of myhiddenid should be here!!
                //and should contain the ID of the button that i clicked.
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        No: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        allFields.val('').removeClass('ui-state-error');
    }
});


$('.del-fruit')
    .button()
    .click(function() {
    $('#dialog-form')
        .dialog( "option", "title", this.id )
        .dialog('open');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with first answer, but if you want to use a hidden div:

set:

```
$("div#myhiddenid").html("whateverId");
```

get:

```
var foo = $("div#myhiddenid").html();
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of a div, you can use hidden field and assign it's value: For e.g.

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnId" />
```

jQuery

```
$("#hdnId").val(id);
```

Comment: So if I follow your suggestion, the jQuery should be placed after this code .dialog('open');

Comment: you can place it above or below `.dialog('close');` line.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to use the jQuery .data() function to store information against an element, for instance against the #dialog-form itself, and use it to represent the information coming back from the dialog. This would be handy if you found yourself needing to return more than just a simple ID, because you could store an object directly rather than having to serialise the information back and forth from hidden fields.

Here is an example based on your HTML: http://jsbin.com/omexi5

When the document loads, each button in the table is assigned a click handler that first records it's ID in the dialog's .data() and then it opens the dialog. The dialog's 'open' event handler uses the ID from .data() to set the message inside the dialog and then the Yes handler uses it to find and update the table button's text.

Hope it helps.